# Value comparision on javascript, but showing incorrect result

Tags: javascript

I want to show 0 when amount is 0,1
I want to show 1 when amount is 2,3
I want to show 2 when amount is greater than 3

I have below javascript but not showing correct result.

```
<script>
{
    var amount = 8; //example amount
    var x = 0;

    if (0 < amount < 2) {
        x = 0;
    } if (1 < amount < 4) {
        x = 1;
    } if (3 < amount) {
        x = 2;
    }     
document.write(x)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate problems there:

1. That's not how compound comparisons work in JavaScript (or most other programming languages, but not all!).

   You use two separate comparisons and an "and" operator:

   ```
   if (0 < amount && amount < 2)
   ```

   What you're doing actually ends up working like this:

   1. Evaluate `0 < amount` and get a result, which will be `true` or `false`. Let's call that `r`.
   2. Evaluate `r < 2`.

   When evaluating `r < 2`, it will coerce `r` to be a number. `true` coerces to `1`, and `false` coerces to `0`. So you end up comparing either `1` or `0` to `2`, **not** `amount`.
2. Your `if` statements are all standalone; the second `if` runs whether the first `if`'s condition is true or false. If you want to make a chain of "if this or if this or if this", you need to use `else`:

So:

```
var amount = 8; //example amount
var x = 0;

if (0 < amount && amount < 2) {
//            ^^^^^^^^^^
    x = 0;
} else if (1 < amount && amount < 4) {
//^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^^
    x = 1;
} else if (3 < amount) {
//^^^^
    x = 2;
}     
document.write(x)
```

Comment: @MarkDeol: Yeah, it's not at all unreasonable to expect `0 < amount < 2` to work. It just doesn't in nearly any of the languages whose syntax derives from B (so that's C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, and several others). There **are** languages that do what you were expecting in that regard.